# Arrays in macros

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

How would I change the following formula to an array in a macro?

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
.Range (BV2:BV & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "IFERROR(INDEX(RC[12]:RC[15],MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(RC[12]:RC[15]),0)),"")"
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `x1up` xhould be `xlup` with a lowercase `L` not the number `1`.
2. you will need to insert the array formula using `.FormulaArray` in the first cell then drag down.
3. you are missing the quotes around the range
4. `"` need to be doubled in the formula string.
5. All formula must have `=` to start the string

---

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
.Range("BV2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(RC[12]:RC[15],MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(RC[12]:RC[15]),0)),"""")"
.Range("BV2").AutoFill .Range("BV2:Bv" & lr)
```